# What event handler is best in using Data Grid View fire on Click in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem with DataGridView event handler *CellContentClick* sometimes it does not work.

here is my code:

```
Private Sub DGV_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV.CellContentClick
        ownDataSelected()
    End Sub
```

Please help me. Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DataGridView.CellClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This event occurs when any part of a cell is clicked, including
>   borders and padding. It also occurs when the user presses and releases
>   the SPACE key while a button cell or check box cell has focus, and
>   will occur twice for these cell types if the cell is clicked while
>   pressing the SPACE key.

`DataGridView.CellContentClick` triggers only on the text of the cell being click and the blank space not count.